# How do I use the Microsoft Word API and Bookmarks feature to programmatically add different text to the same bookmark collection?

Tags: .net, ms-word, bookmarks

I am trying to bookmark all the fields with text 'sample' in a word document. I need to bookmark all of them with the bookmark Name "fld_sample". I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word API to do this programatically. The code below is sample code that I have tried from my end.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Reflection; 

Object oTrue = true; Object oFalse = false;
Application oWord = new Application();
Document oWordDoc = new Document();
oWord.Visible = true;
Object oTemplatePath = @"string Path";

oWordDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref      oMissing);

//selecting the range of text to bookmark.
Range rng = oWordDoc.Range(12, 18);

 oWordDoc.Bookmarks.Add("fld_sample", rng);

 //selecting the next range of text to bookmark with same name
 Range rng1 = oWordDoc.Range(102, 108);

 oWordDoc.Bookmarks.Add("fld_sample", rng1);
```

But the bookmark is only added for second range of values and not for first range of text.
Can anyone help me with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each bookmark needs to have a unique name.  Your second call effectively *reassigns* bookmark 'fld_sample'.  If you want to have a set you can refer to in a loop in code, name subsequent bookmarks something like 'fld_sample2', 'fld_sample3' etc.

Comment: That wouldn't work in my case. My requirement is that, I need to bookmark all the occurances of word 'sample' in the entire word document with same name. so that, in my second use case I will use this bookmarked word document and replace all the bookmark with name 'fld_sample' with some other text provided by the user.

Comment: I get your *requirement*, but that's not how Word bookmarks *work*. You're gong to need to work out a programmable naming scheme and process the bookmarks in a loop.  Or do a no-bookmark text replace.